# Setting different coordinate limits (xlim or ylim) for different geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting multiple predictive values of my logistic regression given different values of my covariates. Essentially what I need to do is set a respective xlim() for each different geom plotted. Here is an example using 2 different geoms:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = wt)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = qsec))
```

Within this example, how could I restrict geom_point to only show specific values (say xlim(15,20)) while geom_smooth has a different (say xlim(25,30))? Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can subset data using a function in place of a `data.frame` for the `data` parameter of a layer. This function will be provided the global data given as argument of `ggplot`, and the result will be used by the layer.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(y = wt), 
    data = function(data) {
      data[data$mpg>=15 & data$mpg<=20,]
    }
  ) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = qsec))
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this. I just wanted to give a more general approach using standard R as OP's question is very basic.

Comment: No need to argue indefinitely :-) I agree with you. I was just following the original intent where the data was given as a global parameter for the whole plot and that it only needs to be filtered for a specific layer, this is why layer's data can be provided a function to do so.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I actually misunderstood! Yep, that seems to work. I actually didn't even know that you can pass the data like this. Very nice.

Comment: Awesome! this was a great solution and did exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks for helping me through this one.

Answer (score 2):

As a variation of @Billy34's approach, you could use:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = wt), ~subset(., mpg >=15 & mpg <=20)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = qsec))
```

`geom_*` functions have `data` as their second parameter, for which we can use tidyverse syntax to make a lambda function to manipulate the data, using the base `subset` function similarly to how we might use `dplyr::filter`.

[image]

Comment: (Do I have my terminology right? I'd appreciate any edits to state this more clearly / correctly.)

Comment: Good point. I was not aware of this one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ggplot_build` to filter on both the geom layers their `x` values. So first filter for your first layer `[[1]]` and second layer `[[2]]` to show the respective ranges you want. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = wt)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = qsec))

q <- ggplot_build(p)

# first layer is geom point
q$data[[1]] <- q$data[[1]][q$data[[1]]$x >= 15 & q$data[[1]]$x <= 20, ]
# second layer is geom smooth
q$data[[2]] <- q$data[[2]][q$data[[2]]$x >= 25 & q$data[[2]]$x <= 30, ]

q <- ggplot_gtable(q)

plot(q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Or use `layer_data` which I find a bit shorter than the way via ggplot_build. It's of course the same

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I really appreciate the help! I was able to successfully achieve my goal using the suggestion above from @tjebo

Comment: @jclifto8 not my suggestion! all credit goes to user Billy34

Comment: I misread, sorry @Billy34 and thanks for the help!